# How to use thisArg in Lo-Dash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

How do I use the thisArg in Lo-Dash? Is it possible to combine it with chaining? This is an example that uses thisArg from their documentation:

```
_.map(collection, [callback=identity], [thisArg])

Creates an array of values by running each element in the collection through the callback. The callback is bound to thisArg and invoked with three arguments; (value, index|key, collection).

If a property name is provided for callback the created "_.pluck" style callback will return the property value of the given element.

If an object is provided for callback the created "_.where" style callback will return true for elements that have the properties of the given object, else false.

Aliases

_.collect

Arguments

collection (Array|Object|string): The collection to iterate over.
[callback=identity] (Function|Object|string): The function called per iteration. If a property name or object is provided it will be used to create a ".pluck" or ".where" style callback, respectively.
[thisArg] (*): The this binding of callback.
Returns

(Array): Returns a new array of the results of each callback execution.
```

An example would be appreciated, as I wasn't able to find any in their documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Argument `thisArg` is just a pointer to `this` context of the caller that will also be used as the context of callback. It is provided for convenience.

The result is the same as if using native `Function.bind()` method e.g.:

```
_.map(collection, callback.bind(this));
```

An alternative approach would be to make an alias variable of `this` and use it instead.

Comment: Is it possible to use this argument to have a variable 'this' binding ? E.g. `O = {foo: function () { return this.bar; }, bar: 42}; A = [O, O]; _.map(A, O.foo, _.identity)` ? (that last expression doesn't work as expected)

Comment: I opened an issue on github directly: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/803